# Rails 4 @posts.each no display post record in web browser

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails so sorry for the simple question. I'm trying to build blog app in rails (ver 4.2.6) from rails tutorial (blog implementation) but after implementing table in Postgresql and fill it with data, I can't receive data from table in web browser.

Code of db/schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160602113240) do

enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

 create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

end
```

Code of file posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @posts = Post.all
end
end
```

Code of file index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.body %></td>
<% end %>
```

In web browser (Chrome served by WEBrick) I see only header **Listing posts**

I have no idea what is going wrong - no errors at all. Records in table exist (checked by pgAdmin), Postgress working. Anybody can help me ?

Update:

After adding `<% raise @posts.inspect %>`

I receive error in browser
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg3BN.png)

Comment: please, provide your controller code

Comment: Could you in your view just write <% raise @posts.inspect %> and give the result please ? Also as Ilya suggested your controller code would be really helpful.

Comment: Also could you please provide the contents of `db/schema.rb`?

Comment: I added all you asked guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed tags for table. Something like

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>
<% if @posts.any? %>
  <table>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
       <td><%= post.title %></td>
       <td><%= post.body %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table>
<% else %>
  <p>No posts</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Add <tr> tags, too.

Comment: Done, thank you :)

Comment: Thank guys - it was that :)